# Bitmap of ListVIew Item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-bitmap

How to create BitMap of a part of an item in a ListView.

Each item of my ListView have 4 components, 2 TextView and 2 Button.
I want to create a BitMap with only 2 TextView when click on a Button.

[image: Here an image to describe my need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your item layout have this components: TextView1, TextView2, Button1, Button2.
You have to put TextView1 and TextView2 in a child layout, to exclude Button1 + Button2 from bitmap, for instance:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <!-- main item layout -->
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutTextViews">
        <!-- child layout for TextViews -->
        <TextView>
        <!-- text view 1 -->
        </TextView>
        <TextView>
        <!-- text view 2 -->
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button>
    <!-- Button 1 -->
    </Button>
    <Button>
    <!-- Button 2 -->
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your java code:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutTextViews);
if (layout != null) {
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getWidth(),
            layout.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas b = new Canvas(image);
    Drawable bgDrawable =layout.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
         bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    layout.draw(b);}
}
```

Comment: thanx it work but back ground of it black

Comment: I edit my answer for black background

Answer (score 0):

What you need is List Adapters.
Take a look at this tutorial section "3. Custom adapter implementations"

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: require a bitmap of listview item for saving it to sd card

Comment: Ah sorry,  I'm removing my response. I'll be back if I get an idea of how to do it.